# Using wp_set_script_translations without manually registering the script

Tags: block-editor, localization

When using `@wordpress/create-block` to scaffhold a plugin for a block, the generated bundle is automatically registered via the `block.json` metadata :

```json
{
  ...
  "name": "my-block",
  "textdomain": "my-block",
  "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
  ...
}
```

No need to call `wp_register_script` myself. This is great since it automatically handles dependencies via the `index.asset.php` file generated in the build folder.

Following the procedure mentionned [in the doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/internationalization/), I then create a JET translation file. Here is the procedure :

1. Creating POT file with `wp i18n make-pot . languages/my-block.pot`
2. Creating PO file with `cp languages/test.pot languages/my-block-FR_BE.po`
3. Filling msgstr strings in `my-block-FR_BE.po`
4. Adding line `"Language: fr_BE\n"` to `my-block-FR_BE.po`
5. Creating JSON file with `wp i18n make-json languages/my-block-FR_BE.po --no-purge`

The JSON generated is appended with a md5 hash: **my-block-fr_BE-cae574befd871d4f740fd8b719bac1db.json**.

Now I have to call `wp_set_script_translations` in my init method :

```php
function my_block_init() {
   register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );
   wp_set_script_translations( 'my-block-script', 'my-block', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages/' );
}
```

This does not work.

In order to make it work, I have to register the script and enqueue it, loosing the ability to have dependencies automatically injected :

```php
function my_block_init() {
    wp_register_script(
        'my-block-script',
        plugins_url('/build/index.js', __FILE__),
        array('react', 'wp-block-editor', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-react-refresh-runtime')
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('my-block-script');
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );

    wp_set_script_translations('my-block-script', 'my-block', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages/');
}
```

I also need to rename my JSON file to include the script handle instead of the automatically generated md5 hash. The ["Load Translation File"](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/internationalization/#load-translation-file) section in the doc gives me the impression that this shouldn't be necessary when keeping the generated name, though I'm not sure of what I'm supposed to do here :

> WordPress will check for a file in that path with the format ${domain}-${locale}-${handle}.json as the source of translations. Alternatively, instead of the registered handle you can use the md5 hash of the relative path of the file, ${domain}-${locale} in the form of ${domain}-${locale}-${md5}.json.

Is there a way to register JET translations for a script that is automatically registered via the block metadata ? And how can I use the generated name for the JSON file when registering my translation ?

#### Edit

Here's the folder structure :

```
app/plugins/my-block/
├── build
│   ├── block.json
│   └── index.asset.php
│   └── index.css
│   └── index.js
│   └── style-index.css
├── languages
│   ├── my-block.pot
│   └── my-block-fr_BE.po
│   └── my-block-fr_BE-my-block-script.json
├── src
│   ├── block.json
│   └── index.js
│   └── ...
└── my-block.php
```

And here's the content of the `my-block.php` file (plugin root) :

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       My Block
 * Requires at least: 5.9
 * Requires PHP:      7.0
 * Version:           0.1.0
 * Author:            The WordPress Contributors
 * License:           GPL-2.0-or-later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       my-block
 */

function my_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );

    wp_set_script_translations( 'my-block-script', 'my-block', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages/' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_block_init' );
```

Comment: I thought that it was automatically loaded if you used it via `block.json` the same way the script and styles were, is that not the case? Are you sure that `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages/'` is the actual folder? If you're not doing this in the main plugin folder then `__FILE__` will have the incorrect value and `plugin_dir_path` will return an incorrect result, `plugin_dir_path` is expecting the main file of the plugin, not the current file the code is in.

Comment: the call to `wp_set_script_translations` is in the main plugin php file at the root of the plugin.

Comment: have you checked the actual value directly and made sure it is indeed resolving to the correct directory? Ignore the fact that it's supposed to be or that it _should_ be correct, and check if it actually is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @TomJNowell. I did check the path, and it works when I register and enqueue the script manually so I would think WP can see the language files.

My workaround doesn't work on my staging environment for some reason, so I'm back at trying to make it work automatically. I added the folder structure in the OP if that can help, maybe the structure generated with @wordpress/create-block is not working for i18n'd blocks.

Comment: can you make sure that you include not just your functions, but the `add_action` calls you used, and make sure they're in the order they are in your codebase too. It's possible the order things are called in is causing issues, eitherway seeing the code will help eliminate that question. ( note that the packages you're using to generate this have changed over time so simply referring to what the package does as the answer isn't enough )

Comment: Sure, I added the content of the root php file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[@drskullster](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/29500/drskullster) already posted a good answer, but I thought I should share the following which explains why [`wp_set_script_translations()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_script_translations/) needs to be called manually:

1. Yes it's true that WordPress will automatically register and enqueue the block editor script. ***So we do not need to manually register/enqueue that script!***
2. WordPress will also automatically set the script's translations, but only if the block metadata file (i.e. `block.json`) specifies a valid text domain (e.g. `"textdomain": "gutenpride"`) and that the script has `wp-i18n` as one of its dependencies. See [`register_block_script_handle()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_script_handle/).
3. WordPress uses `wp_set_script_translations( $script_handle, $metadata['textdomain'] )` to register/set the translations for the script, which means the 3rd parameter (the file path) is not specified and therefore, WordPress will try to load the translation files from the `wp-content/languages/plugins` folder.

   So for example, if `my-block-fr_BE-dfbff627e6c248bcb3b61d7d06da9ca9.json` was the JSON file name, then WordPress would attempt to load `wp-content/languages/plugins/my-block-fr_BE-dfbff627e6c248bcb3b61d7d06da9ca9.json`.

   And thus, you should copy that file to the `wp-content/languages/plugins` folder. That way, your main plugin file would only need to call `register_block_type()` and that's it — no need to worry about the JSON file name or MD5 hash, and you also would **not** need to *manually* call `wp_set_script_translations()`.

But if you don't want to having to copy the files, then yes, you will need to manually call `wp_set_script_translations()`, but remember that the **script handle** is in the form of `<block name>-editor-script` where `<block name>` is the block name (which is the `name` property in `block.json`), but with *slashes (`/`) replaced with hypens (`-`)*.

- So if the block name is `my-block`, then the script handle would be `my-block-editor-script`. Or if the name is `create-block/gutenpride`, then the handle would be `create-block-gutenpride-editor-script`. See [`generate_block_asset_handle()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/generate_block_asset_handle/) for more details.

So I hope that helps, and FYI, the following is what I had in my main plugin file (`wp-content/plugins/gutenpride/gutenpride.php`):

```php
function create_block_gutenpride_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );

    // Load MO files for PHP.
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'gutenpride', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );

    // Load JSON files for JS - this is necessary if using a custom languages path!!
    $script_handle = generate_block_asset_handle( 'create-block/gutenpride', 'editorScript' );
    wp_set_script_translations( $script_handle, 'gutenpride', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_gutenpride_block_init' );
```

- Note: I followed the same steps as in your procedure, but I got an extra step — I created an MO file for use in standard PHP translations, e.g. `<?php _e( 'text', 'gutenpride' ); ?>`.

#### Additional Notes

1. If the 3rd parameter for `wp_set_script_translations()` is specified and the path/folder contains a JSON translations file named `<text domain>-<locale>-<script handle>.json`, e.g. `gutenpride-fr_BE-create-block-gutenpride-editor-script.json`, then WordPress will attempt to load that *first*.

   So if the file doesn't exist, then WordPress will attempt to load the default one with the MD5 hash, e.g. `gutenpride-fr_BE-dfbff627e6c248bcb3b61d7d06da9ca9.json`.
2. [`load_script_translations()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_script_translations/) is the function used to load translations from script translations files, i.e. that function opens the file and reads its content; and the function applies filters like [`load_script_translation_file`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load_script_translation_file/) which you may find useful when debugging.. :)
3. My "Gutenpride" block was tried & tested with WordPress v6.0, and the latest version of the @wordpress/create-block package at the time of writing.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you ! Can you also explain why we should call `wp_set_script_translations` during the `init` hook and not during `wp_enqueue_scripts` as suggested above ?

Comment: See the source code of [`_wp_scripts_maybe_doing_it_wrong()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.0/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L30-L69) which is used by `wp_register_script()` (and `wp_enqueue_script()`, too). And in that source, `_doing_it_wrong()` is skipped if the `init` hook has run, which means it can be used to register scripts.

Comment: And although indirectly, `register_block_type()` will  automatically register the block editor script (and other scripts like `viewScript`, if set in the block metadata), so I wouldn't say we should call `wp_set_script_translations()` during the `init` hook, but it's that we **can** call it because the script *has already been registered via `register_block_type()`*. You can also see the official Gutenberg examples also used the same hook, e.g. [this](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/blob/8e20a009dc8b70ba87bb200804d293897d375303/blocks-jsx/01-basic-esnext/index.php#L39).

Comment: automatically created handle is in the form block-name-editor-script, but if slash is in the name, then it is replaced by hyphen - so for "maintainer/block" is "maintainer-block-editor-script"

Comment: My answer did state that "*slashes (/) replaced with hypens (-)*", but thanks @Lovor :)

Comment: Yes indeed, this is because of superficial reading - sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I managed to make it work :

I found the handle of the script registered automatically with `register_block_type` by printing the `$this->registered` variable inside the `WP_Scripts->set_translations` method, it was called something like `my-block-editor-script`.

By using this handle inside the call to `wp_set_script_translations` I was able to remove the code that registered and enqueued the script, and I also could use the generated name for the json files.

Here's what my main plugin file looks like now :

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       My Block
 * Requires at least: 5.9
 * Requires PHP:      7.0
 * Version:           0.1.0
 * Text Domain:       my-block
 */

function my_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_block_init' );

function my_block_set_translations() {
    wp_set_script_translations( 'my-block-editor-script', 'my-block',  plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages/' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_block_set_translations' );
```

And the path to the JET file: `languages/my-block-fr_BE-dfbff627e6c248bcb3b61d7d06da9ca9.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```php
    wp_set_script_translations( 'my-block-script', 'my-block', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages/' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_block_init' );
```

`init` is too early, WP hasn't registered your blocks assets yet, it knows about the block but that doesn't mean it instantly did all the work all at once in a single atomic step. If it registered and enqueued the scripts and styles on `init` it would generate warnings and doing it wrong notices!

And as the docs say:

> Works only if the script has already been registered.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_script_translations/

It's too early!!! A useful thing to do is check the return value which is a `true`/`false` indicating success.

Instead, call it on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook the same way the docs say `wp_enqueue_script` and others should be called, but give it a higher priority value on the hook to ensure it runs afterwards.

Here's a useful example from the official WP docs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_script_translations/#comment-5072

Comment: Still not working. When hooking to `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a priority of 100, the `wp_set_script_translations` call returns `false`. When registering and enqueuing manually, the script returns `true`. Should I set the handle value to something specific ? Do you know how Wordpress reconciles the automatic registering with `register_block_type` and the `wp_set_script_translations` call ?

Comment: hmmm, my suspicion is that this is being conditionally loaded only when the block is in use

Comment: I printed the `$this->registered` variable inside the `WP_Scripts->set_translations` method, and got the handle from that: `my-block-editor-script`. Using this handle, the `wp_set_script_translations` returns `true` without having to manually register and enqueue the script, so that's progress ! But... It still doesn't work (my workaround method doesn't work anymore so it may be due to other changes I made while debugging). Do you know where I can look in the source code for the actual injection of the messages inside the client's `wp.i18n` variable ?

Comment: have you tried doing this without your workaround?

Comment: The workaround I'm referring to is registering and enqueuing manually. I did try without it, and now that I know the handle generated by `register_block_type` I don't need the workaround anymore.

Comment: I finally got it to work. Thanks for your help @Tom J Nowell. Finding the handle was the breakthrough, though nothing is mentionned in the doc regarding having to use a specific handle name. And I had to revert to hooking to `init`, hooking to `wp_enqueue_scripts` never worked (the method was called but the strings inside the json file were never added to the `wp.i18n` object). Note that `init` is what is used in the doc on block internationalization.