# Custom plugin translation not working

Tags: plugins, php, jquery, plugin-qtranslate, react

I made a plugin that contains 2 custom gutenberg blocks created with react and jQuery (for some front-end stuff) and I'm having troubles translating them. There are no translation strings inside the PHP files. Basically there are no PHP files, except for the main plugin file, the settings and another file where I'm doing enqueue of Google Places and Google ReCapcha. Inside my main PHP file I have specified in the top section my text domain, then I have 2 functions:

```
function gutenberg_blocks_init(){
    register_block_type(
        __DIR__ . '/build/block-a/',
    );
    register_block_type(
        __DIR__ . '/build/block-b/',
    );
}
add_action('init', 'gutenberg_blocks_init')
```

and

```
function load_translations() {
    load_plugin_textdomain('myblocks', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/languages/');
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'load_translations' )
```

Inside my index.js and inside my jQuery front-end file I'm doing `import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n'` and all the strings are written as it should - `__( 'String to translate', 'myblocks' )`. I generated a POT file using WP-CLI and from there I translated all the strings using PoEdit and created PO and MO files. The POT file successfully got all the strings from the js files. Yet the translations are not working.. Tried instead of all this to use Loco Translate, but it's not working again.. Is there anything that I'm missing? How can I translate my blocks? Tried a bunch of different ways and none of them worked so far.. Tried with json files and `wp_set_script_translations`, but didn't quite understand what to do and it didn't worked..

Comment: The accepted answer to this WordPress Stack Exchange question should help: [Using wp_set_script_translations without manually registering the script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/407346). You might have to rename the `*.po` files, find the correct script handle, and use **wp_set_script_translations** with the correct script handle and domain.

Comment: @kofeigen, thanks that was really helpful. I was able to translate my react files, but still no success with the translations in my frontend.js (jQuery)..

Comment: When you generate the .json, are all the translations in one file (per language)? Or do you get several .json files per language?

Comment: @kofeigen, I get multiple json files. One for index.js (the react block) and one for frontend.js (the jQuery).. Tried with different handles and different ways to import wp.i18n in my frontend.js, but none worked.. So I made a workaround by transfering all my jQuery strings inside my react and passing them as data attributes to the elements, then in my frontend.js file I just grab the already translated strings, since the react translations are working fine. Not the best solution honestly, but to be fair I only had like 4 strings in my jQuery..